# How to fix the error in 'spreadsheet' gem (Unknown Codepage 0x906c)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, spreadsheet, roo-gem

I need to get information from the xls file for that was involved gem 'roo'.
When I try to read a file, I get an error.

Please help fix this error!

My code:

```
require 'roo'
require 'spreadsheet'
require 'open-uri'

x = Roo::Excel.new("http://EXAMPLE.COM/EXAMPLE.xls")
x.cell 31,'F'
```

> ### RuntimeError: Unknown Codepage 0x906c   from /home/hender/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spreadsheet-0.9.7/lib/spreadsheet/excel/reader.rb:75:in
>
> `block in encoding'   from
>   /home/hender/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spreadsheet-0.9.7/lib/spreadsheet/excel/reader.rb:74:in`
>   fetch'   from
>   /home/hender/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spreadsheet-0.9.7/lib/spreadsheet/excel/reader.rb:74:in
>   `encoding'   from
>   /home/hender/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spreadsheet-0.9.7/lib/spreadsheet/excel/reader.rb:211:in`
>   read_codepage'   from
>   /home/hender/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spreadsheet-0.9.7/lib/spreadsheet/excel/reader.rb:821:in
>   `read_workbook'   from
>   /home/hender/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spreadsheet-0.9.7/lib/spreadsheet/excel/reader.rb:135:in`
>   read'   from
>   /home/hender/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spreadsheet-0.9.7/lib/spreadsheet/excel/workbook.rb:32:in
>   `open'   from
>   /home/hender/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spreadsheet-0.9.7/lib/spreadsheet.rb:63:in`
>   open'   from
>   /home/hender/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spreadsheet-0.9.7/lib/spreadsheet.rb:69:in
>   `open'   from
>   /home/hender/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/roo-1.13.2/lib/roo/excel.rb:40:in`
>   block in initialize'   from
>   /home/hender/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/roo-1.13.2/lib/roo/base.rb:565:in
>   `block in make_tmpdir'   from
>   /home/hender/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tmpdir.rb:88:in`
>   mktmpdir'   from
>   /home/hender/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/roo-1.13.2/lib/roo/base.rb:564:in
>   `make_tmpdir'   from
>   /home/hender/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/roo-1.13.2/lib/roo/excel.rb:31:in`
>   initialize'   from /home/hender/helloapp/app/models/mode.rb:26:in
>   `new'   from /home/hender/helloapp/app/models/mode.rb:26:in`hello'
>   ... 2 levels...   from
>   /home/hender/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in
>   `start'   from
>   /home/hender/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:69:in`
>   console'   from
>   /home/hender/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in
>   `run_command!'   from
>   /home/hender/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in`
>   '   from
>   /home/hender/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'   from
>   /home/hender/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in`block in require'   from
>   /home/hender/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'   from
>   /home/hender/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in`require'   from /home/hender/helloapp/bin/rails:8:in `<top
>   (required)>'   from
>   /home/hender/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in`load'   from
>   /home/hender/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'   from
>   /home/hender/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in`load_dependency'   from
>   /home/hender/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'   from
>   /home/hender/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`
>   require'   from
>   /home/hender/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
>   `require'     from -e:1:in`'2.1.2 :004 > ^C
>       2.1.2 :004 >##

Answer (score 0):

In my case i have to deal with a CODEPAGE problem with spreadsheet gem. After some research i found that is a format on the file itself that will depend on some characteristics of it.

Here some information from the Gem itself:
https://github.com/zdavatz/spreadsheet/blob/master/lib/spreadsheet/excel/internals.rb#L15

My solution was grabbing the original file and send it to a online conversor. From there transform it to xls (no matter if it was already an xls format).

Wish it helps!